# Dynamic object can't find method

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have the following code:

```
public T Dispatch<T>(IQuery<T> query)
{
    Type type = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>);
    Type[] typeArgs = { query.GetType(), typeof(T) };
    Type handlerType = type.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

    dynamic handler = _provider.Resolve(handlerType);
    T result = handler.Handle((dynamic)query);

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I have resolved the correct IQueryHandler:
[image]

I get the following exception:
`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Handle''`

I use .NET Framework 4.6.1, and this is the highest version I could use in our organization. So I guess the features I need are not supported in C#7. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: And you're sure the object does have a Handle method? It's not explicitly defined through an interface or something?

Comment: can you please post that handler class as well?

Comment: Apparently my handler had internal as access modifier. Setting it to public did the trick.